# How can I initialize sigset_t or other variables used as "out parameters" in Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi, libc, out-parameters

I'm trying to learn more about FFI in Rust and linking with C libraries, specifically `libc`. While on my "quest", I came across the following problem.

#### Normal pattern in C

```c
void(* sig_set(int sig, void(*handler)(int))) {
    // uninitialized sigaction structs
    struct sigaction new_action, old_action;

    // assign options to new action
    new_action.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    new_action.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&new_action.sa_mask);

    if(sigaction(sig, &new_action, &old_action) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s!\n", "signal error");
        exit(1);
    }
    return old_action.sa_handler;
}
```

#### Attempt in Rust

```rust
use libc; // 0.2.77

fn sig_init(sig: i32, handler: fn(i32) -> ()) -> usize {
    unsafe {
        let mut new_action: libc::sigaction;
        let mut old_action: libc::sigaction;

        new_action.sa_flags = 0x10000000;
        new_action.sa_sigaction = handler as usize;
        libc::sigemptyset(&mut new_action.sa_mask as *mut libc::sigset_t);

        libc::sigaction(
            sig,
            &mut new_action as *mut libc::sigaction,
            &mut old_action as *mut libc::sigaction,
        );
        old_action.sa_sigaction
    }
}
```

The compiler will throw the following error:

```
error[E0381]: assign to part of possibly-uninitialized variable: `new_action`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         new_action.sa_flags = 0x10000000;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `new_action`

error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `old_action`
  --> src/lib.rs:15:13
   |
15 |             &mut old_action as *mut libc::sigaction,
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `old_action`
```

This makes sense as very bad things could happen if `sigemptyset` were to read from `sa_mask`. So I tried the following on line 3 of the above.

```
let mut new_action: libc::sigaction = libc::sigaction {
    sa_sigaction: handler as usize,
    sa_flags: 0x10000000,
    sa_mask: mask,
};
```

This will not work as `_restorer` is missing in the above example, but `_restorer` is private. How would I get around this problem or a similar situation? Would you use something like `mem::transmute`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library defines a couple of types and functions to deal with initialization. They are generic, so they can be used to initialize values of any type.

Modern Rust suggests using [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) in most cases. Applied to your case, it would look something like:

```rust
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

let mut new_action: libc::sigaction = MaybeUninit::zeroed().assume_init();
let mut old_action: libc::sigaction = MaybeUninit::zeroed().assume_init();
```

`MaybeUninit` was stabilized in Rust 1.36. Before that, you could use  [`std::mem::uninitialized()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html), which gives you an uninitialized value. LLVM will consider the contents to be undefined, and will perform aggressive optimizations based on this. You *must* initialize any value before it's read.

More appropriate to your case, there's [`std::mem::zeroed()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.zeroed.html), which gives you a value whose storage is filled with zeroes. This function is `unsafe` because such a value is not necessarily legal for all types. `zeroed()` is appropriate for "plain old data" (POD) types. Applied to your case, it would look something like:

```rust
use std::mem;

let mut new_action: libc::sigaction = mem::zeroed();
let mut old_action: libc::sigaction = mem::zeroed();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`mem::zeroed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.zeroed.html)? The docs even say:

> This is useful for FFI functions sometimes, but should generally be avoided.