# Getting "use of possibly uninitialized variable" for a struct member while explicitly initializing it

Tags: rust

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
error[E0381]: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `mbinfo.flags`
   --> kernel/src/loader/mod.rs:256:20
    |
256 |     mbinfo.flags = mbinfo.flags | multiboot::MULTIBOOT_INFO_CMDLINE;
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly uninitialized `mbinfo.flags`
```

and this is the code:

```
let mut mbinfo: multiboot::multiboot_info;
mbinfo.flags = 0 as u32;
mbinfo.flags = mbinfo.flags | multiboot::MULTIBOOT_INFO_CMDLINE
```

Even though I am explicitly initializing it, I get the error. I've tried making the struct derive Default, but the problem is that the struct contains unions, and when I try to derive Default, I get

```
error: this trait cannot be derived for unions
```

Any easy way out? Thanks.

The multiboot module was auto generated by bindgen from a header file.

MWE on Rust Playground, code is at the end:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=464b7fb21fc75a54618b14619076d152

Comment: You only init `flags`, not `mbinfo`. Why not construct a `multiboot_info` properly ? Please provide a [mcve], this question need it.

Comment: Because it's generated by bindgen from a large linux header file, reimplementing it would be a waste of effort. Added MWE to question.

Comment: The word **Minimal** in [MCVE] is just as important as the other words. The fact that your code cannot even be included on Stack Overflow is a really good sign that it's not **minimal**.

Comment: Your playground code does not produce the error you are asking about — not only is it not *minimal*, it's not **verifiable**.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Initializing sigset_t in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34377051/155423); [Why does the compiler warn about an uninitialized variable even though I've assigned each field of that variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46578050/155423); [Is it possible to mark a potentially uninitialized variable as good without using unsafe or panicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45371062/155423). If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster first one probably fixes it and it doesn't show on my google search for the error, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
error[E0381]: assign to part of possibly uninitialized variable: `mbinfo`
    --> src/lib.rs:1178:4
     |
1178 |    mbinfo.flags = 0;
     |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly uninitialized `mbinfo`
```

The compiler tells you the exact problem: you are trying to work with an uninitialized struct. You are trying to initialize only one field of struct, Rust doesn't allow that.

`multiboot_info` doesn't implement the `Default` trait, so you need to figure out how to create it using its API.